# Is it reasonable to assume that de Sitter temperature will stop growing when it reaches equilibrium with the temperature of CMB?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, de-sitter-spacetime

Is it reasonable to assume that de Sitter temperature will stop growing when it reaches equilibrium with the temperature of CMB?

Currently the de Sitter temperature (the temperature of the Universe's boundary) is $$T_{dS}=2.67\times10^{-30}\,\mathrm K$$

and rises.

At the same time, the temperature of CMB is $$T_{cmb}=2.7\,\mathrm K$$

and falls.

I wonder, does it mean that at the moment they will equate, the de Sitter temperature will stop growth, and so the expansion of the universe will also stop accelerating, thus reaching the thermodynamic equilibrium?

In other words, whether the excessive temperature of CMB compared to the de Sitter temperature is the main source of the accelerated cosmic expansion?

Comment: Is there such a thing as the *Universe's boundary* in a de Sitter space-time ?

Comment: @V. Rossetto apparently.

Comment: Could you provide a reference on the de Sitter temperature to explain under what principles it is computed ?

Comment: @Anixx: Why would you think that dS temperature is rising?

Comment: @V.Rossetto: The original reference is Gibbons, G.W.,  Hawking, S. W. (1977). *Cosmological event horizons, thermodynamics, and particle creation*. Phys. Rev. D, 15(10), 2738. [doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.15.2738), For overview look at Bousso, R. (2002). *Adventures in de Sitter space*. [arXiv:hep-th/0205177](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205177).